# changing the size of column using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, column-sizing

I met some troubles while using PHPExcel,

In fact I have read all the tutorials I've found but it does not work for me.

I've put this code on the page:

```
$i = -1; // index des enregistrements

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(75);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(150);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(190);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(150);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(115);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(115);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(380);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(75);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', '<img src="images/agenda.png" alt="AGENDA" width="168" height="24">');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A3', 'Du '.$_REQUEST['date1'].' Au '.$_REQUEST['date2'].', Critères: '.$_REQUEST['tache'] );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', 'CLIENT');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B5', 'N° DE DOSSIER');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C5', 'DEBITEUR');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D5', 'TEL');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E5', 'DATE');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F5', 'TRAITEMENT');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G5', 'DESCRIPTION');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H5', 'RESTANT DU EN PPAL');
```

But it give to me the following errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: sheet in Line 173

Notice: Undefined variable: sheet in Line 173

I'm really Lost, I thought it wad that way for changing column sizes.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

SP.

Comment: There aren't 173 lines in the code you have posted. Note also that what you are getting are not errors, and they should not break the program flow.

Comment: I know but the following first line does refer to the line 173. Actualy I have yet small column And I would like to see all data in that column. This is my line 173 $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(75);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define $sheet before using it, like any variable in PHP it doesn't exist until it's actually created; but you also want it to be the actual PHPExcel worksheet where you want to set the column widths.

So

instead of

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

use

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

which works because a call to the setActiveSheetIndex() returns the active worksheet object

Once $sheet has been defined as the current Worksheet, you can make your calls to set the column widths

**EDIT**

Then you can also simplify your calls to set cell values from

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', '<img src="images/agenda.png" alt="AGENDA" width="168" height="24">
```

to

```
$sheet->SetCellValue('D1', '<img src="images/agenda.png" alt="AGENDA" width="168" height="24">
```

etc

**Note** however that setting HTML markup in a cell is simply setting cell to contain a text string, this will not embed an image in your worksheet

Comment: You are a Genius, thank you so much for the precious help, I appreciate it